# Get witness disk current vote via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, failovercluster

I am trying to verify functionality of dynamic quorum in a new failover cluster setup.

Is there a command in PowerShell that I can use to see the current vote for the witness disk? I have been digging through TechNet, and have been unsuccessful locating the command (if it even exists in the first place).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Windows Server 2012 R2, "The clustering service will automatically assign the witness a vote, the witness dynamic vote, depending on if there is an odd or even number of votes present for the cluster nodes."

[Dynamic Witness in Windows Server 2012 R2 Failover Clustering](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-server-2012-r2/dynamic-witness-windows-server-2012-r2-failover-clustering)

"To check the vote status of the witness, use the Windows PowerShell command below. A return of 1 means the witness has a vote; a return of 0 means the witness doesn't have a vote."

(Get-Cluster).WitnessDynamicWeight